# Cast to a type dynamically according to the variable type in java

Tags: java, casting

I have a HashMap and a class named Plugin that contains all the variables that needs to be mapped from the map I mentioned.
I just want to cast the value of the key (in the Map) according to the type of variable declared in the class for that key.
Let say,

--> Map entries :
.
.
result : "SUCCESS"
.
.

--> Variable in Plugin class

```
private String result;
```

Now I want to cast the value of the key "result" to the type of variable result in Plugin class.
I tried using

```
this.result = this.result.getClass().cast(map.get("result"));
```

and this also

```
this.result = (this.result.getClass())map.get("result");
```

Thanks

Comment: You cannot cast to a "dynamic type". Use *Interfaces* (and a well-planned structure) instead.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127318/java-how-can-i-do-dynamic-casting-of-a-variable-from-one-type-to-another?rq=1 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21244993/java-dynamically-cast-object-reference-to-references-class?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

As simple as breathing:

```
result = (String) map.get("result");
```

Or

```
result = map.get("result").toString();
```

Comment: I want to get rid of the Class name while casting. I want to make it generic so that I need not change the conversion function. Here if I change the type of result to Integer then I need to change the code also.

Comment: Good luck on your adventure

Answer (score 0):

Actually, such "dynamic casting" is impossible in Java due to early binding. Compiler checks, whether type in the right part is a subtype of the type of the left part.

`this.result.getClass()` returns variable of type `Class`, its value is unknown in compiler time, so compiler does not know type of the cast result and therefore cannot assign result of your cast to the `Plugin.result` field.

You could get messy with reflection, but it is not worthy for your case.

I suggest you use [BeanUtils.populate(Plugin pligin, Map map)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html#populate%28java.lang.Object,%20java.util.Map%29) to transfer your properties.

See also [java: how can i do dynamic casting of a variable from one type to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127318/java-how-can-i-do-dynamic-casting-of-a-variable-from-one-type-to-another?rq=1)